# docker Elasticsearch 5.6.10 how to remove username & password

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I've ran this command

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.10
```

and then up the docker by this command

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.10
```

But seems this version will set an default user name & password:
elastic:changeme

Do anyone how to remove the username password?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't until, you enable the x-pack basic security, can you share how its asking for the username and password and share the startup logs by using below command.

```
docker logs <your-es-conatiner-id>
```

Edit: I tried it myself and saw x-pack plugin is loaded as shown in below log

```
[2020-08-27T10:50:24,913][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IioZz2W] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
[2020-08-27T10:50:24,913][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [IioZz2W] loaded plugin [x-pack]
```

Also its asking me same username/password, **so you need to disable the x-pack while running the docker conatiner.**

**Adding `-e "xpack.security.enabled=false"` in your docker run command will fix the issue.**

So your run command will be like below

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.10
```